# Prove all limit points of $[a,b]$ are in $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-writing

I know there are similar topics, but I'm trying to get better at providing a proof from scratch. The problem is to show $[a,b]$ is closed and by definition this means that it contains all its limit points. My work so far:

If $x \notin [a,b]$ then either $x<a$ or $x>b$. We will first consider $x<a$. Now, let $\epsilon < a-x$, then the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x$ is $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$. And $$x-\epsilon<x-a+x=2x-a<x<x+\epsilon<x+a-x=a.$$
Thus $x+\epsilon<a$ and this implies that there are no elements of $[a,b]$ in the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x$, thus $x$ is not a limit point of $[a,b]$.

Now we will consider $x>b$ in a similar way. Let $\epsilon<x-b$, then the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x$ is $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$. And $$x-\epsilon<x-x+b=b<x<x+\epsilon<x+x-b=2x-b.$$
But the last line implies that $x-\epsilon<b$, which would mean that $x \in [a,b]$, which is clearly not the case! What do I do wrong!?

Comment: Or could I directly state that if $\epsilon < x-b$ it follows algebraic that $b<x-\epsilon$ which means that there are no elements of $[a,b]$ in the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x$?

Comment: Yes, I have just written below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequalities $2x-b>b$ and $2x-b>x-\epsilon$ together do not imply that $b>x-\epsilon$.

Actually from $\epsilon<x-b$ we are ready to get $b<x-\epsilon$, so no elements of $[a,b]$ in the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $x$.

Comment: Thanks, I now see I can do the same for the first section right? Just go from $\epsilon<a-x$ to $x+\epsilon<a$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof idea is correct, but you need to be more careful in the cases with your inequalities. The error in the second part is when you say $x-\epsilon<x-x+b=b$, this is not true, it is in fact $>$ and not $<$. Make sure you always keep track of whether each replacement is $<$ or $>$, and make sure you think about signs (here we have $-\epsilon$, not $\epsilon$).

Here you seem to be trying to show $x-\epsilon$ is less than something, but you actually want to show it's *greater* than $b$ -- that way there are no elements of $[a,b]$ in the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x$.
So in the second case you should fill in
$$
x - \epsilon > \cdots > b.
$$

Your first case also has some error.
The first line, $x - \epsilon < x - a + x$, is not true -- in fact, $x - \epsilon$ is *greater than* $x - (a - x)$. But you do write the correct statement after that, namely that $x + \epsilon < x + (a - x) = a$.
All you need for this case is to fill in
$$
x + \epsilon < \cdots < a.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the first case I just tried to write out the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x$, so I did mean what I wrote down.. That makes sense right?

Comment: @Mathbeginner What you want to show is $x + \epsilon < a$, you don't need to consider $x - \epsilon$. It doesn't quite make sense to me. Let me see if there is an error I didn't catch.

Comment: @Mathbeginner What you wrote actually had an error. I added clarification in my answer.

Comment: thanks! Makes perfect sense now.